# OpenSSL - Failed to create p12 from private key on bad decrypt

Tags: openssl, private-key, p12

I installed OpenSSL 1.1.1 on windows https://kb.firedaemon.com/support/solutions/articles/4000121705#Download-OpenSSL

I got crt file and I have PrivKey.pem created and I try to generate p12

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in Cert.crt -inkey PrivKey.pem -out KeyStore.p12
```

Output:

```
unable to load private key
18328:error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt:..\crypto\evp\evp_enc.c:615:
18328:error:0906A065:PEM routines:PEM_do_header:bad decrypt:..\crypto\pem\pem_lib.c:461:
```

I notice that when I create private key I don't get password prompt

```
openssl genrsa -aes256 -out PrivKey.pem 2048
```

Output:

```
Generating RSA private key, 2048 bit long modulus (2 primes)
```

Most related answers I found related to wrong configuration/file, but it seems as a different case

Should I reset my settings and renew process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I download and install OpenSSL 1.1.1 **for Linux** and it works without any issue